# Debugging a bundled Meteor App

Tags: meteor, build

I have a Meteor app ready to deploy. If I bundle it as such:

```
meteor build ../output --debug
```

and then deploy it, it works fine. However, when I run:

```
meteor build ../output
```

and then deploy it, it loads up however has a template error in the console. I don't know how to debug this, as all of the code is now minified.

Not sure the best approach to figuring this out!

Comment: Have you tried the reverse, i.e. running in dev but with minification (`meteor run --production`), to see if the bundling process creates your issue?

Comment: What sort of errors are you seeing? Any clue from them?